# Remove duplicates after a certain number of occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, functional-programming, data-science

How do we filter the dataframe below to remove all duplicate ID rows after a certain number of ID occurrence. I.E. remove all rows of `ID == 0` after the 3rd occurrence of `ID == 0`

Thanks

```
 pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 2)), columns=['ID', 'Value']).sort_values('ID')
               
                 Output:
                   ID   Value
                    0   7
                    0   8
                    0   5
                    0   5
                ... ... ...
                    9   7
                    9   7
                    9   1
                    9   3

Desired Output for filter_count = 3:

                 Output:
                   ID   Value
                    0   7
                    0   8
                    0   5
                    1   7
                    1   7
                    1   1
                    2   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this for all IDs, use:

```
df.groupby("ID").head(3)
```

For single ID, you can assign a new column using `cumcount` and then filter by conditions:

```
df["count"] = df.groupby("ID")["Value"].cumcount()

print (df.loc[(df["ID"].ne(0))|((df["ID"].eq(0)&(df["count"]<3)))])

    ID  Value  count
64   0      6      0
77   0      6      1
83   0      0      2
44   1      7      0
58   1      5      1
40   1      2      2
35   1      7      3
89   1      9      4
19   1      7      5
10   1      3      6
45   2      4      0
68   2      1      1
74   2      4      2
75   2      8      3
34   2      4      4
60   2      6      5
78   2      0      6
31   2      8      7
97   2      9      8
2    2      6      9
93   2      8     10
13   2      2     11
...
```

Comment: I suppose OP wants this per all IDs, so `df["ID"].eq(0)` can be removed

Comment: I added a solution for all IDs.

Answer (score 2):

I will do *without* `groupby`

```
df = pd.concat([df.loc[df.ID==0].head(3),df.loc[df.ID!=0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Henry,

I modified your code and I think this should work as well.

Your `df.groupby("ID").head(3)` is great. Thanks.

```
df["count"] = df.groupby("ID")["Value"].cumcount()
df.loc[df["count"]<3].drop(['count'], axis=1)
```